# QML button change text color

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm new in QML and i want to personalize my buttons. I succeed to change the background's color and border color. But I don't success at all to change the color of the button's text. I saw we don't use anymore "style" to change the style but "background" and I don't understand everything about it.

Thanks for your help.

```
Button {
        id: buttonAC
        text: qsTr("AC")
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true

        background: Rectangle {
            border.color: "#14191D"
            color: "#24292f"
            // I want to change text color next
        }

        /*Text {
            text: qsTr("AC")
            color: "#F54035"
        }*/
}
```

Comment: all you need is just to open [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-button) or [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#contentItem-prop)

Comment: Thank you, it resolve my problem, i went on this documentation many times without retrieve the good information. But it was clearly said in the documentation.

Comment: @folibis the if you change the `contentItem` the button will no longer have icon functionality which is a pain to deal with that stuff yourself because if you wont need an icon you will need to create another component or implement states..

Answer (score 21):

According to the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-button)

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Button {
    id: control
    text: qsTr("Button")

    contentItem: Text {
        text: control.text
        font: control.font
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
        color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        elide: Text.ElideRight
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 100
        implicitHeight: 40
        opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.3
        border.color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
        border.width: 1
        radius: 2
    }
}
```

Comment: as was noted above, this won't work if you wish to display an icon as well as text.

Answer (score 21):

The two fastest ways I found were to either use the following undocumented property:

```
Button {
     ....
     palette.buttonText: "white"
}
```

To go even further when customizing text colors during user interaction here is the ternary in the Button source code followed by a list of the properties to set accordingly:

```
color: control.checked || control.highlighted ? control.palette.brightText :
           control.flat && !control.down ? (control.visualFocus ? control.palette.highlight : control.palette.windowText) : control.palette.buttonText
```

Properties:

```
control.palette.brightText
control.palette.highlight
control.palette.windowText
control.palette.buttonText
```

The second dirty hack would be to use the onCompleted slot as follows:

```
Button {
     id: control
     ....
     Component.onCompleted: {
          control.contentItem.color = "white";
     }
}
```

Comment: Best answer, IMO. And palette.buttonText isn't completely undocumented: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-palette.html

Comment: Qt's documentation never ceases to amaze.

Answer (score 7):

If you just wanna change your text color, may you use html font style in your `Button` would be better. This will keeping other `Item` like button icon:

```
Button
{
    //...
    text: "<font color='#fefefe'>" + moudle + "</font>"
    font.family: "Arial"
    font.pointSize: 24
    //...
}
```

Comment: amazing ! you rocks ! i have been fighting the last 15min to set the color of a ToggleButton/ToggleButtonStyle your method worked :) thanks

Answer (score 6):

There is another way if you are using QML Styling. Replace 2.12 with your version of QML.

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12    

Button {
    id: goToParenFolder
    text: "Hi"
    flat: true
    Material.foreground: "red"
}
```

This button's text will be in red and others will follow Material Style coloring.

To enable QML Styling and add the Material theme add `QT += quickcontrols2` to your .pro file.

Also add `#include <QQuickStyle>` and `QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");` to main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

```
Button {
    id: control
    width: 290; height: 80
    opacity: down ? 0.6 : 1
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "#4DABFB"
        radius: 50
    }
    Text {
        id: controlText
        anchors.fill: parent
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        font.pixelSize: 30
        color: "#FFFFFF"
        text: "OK"
    }
}
```

I like use `Text` inside the `Button`, then you can change Text's color as you like.